# Configuring django-tinymce-filebrowser with django-tinymce doesn't work

Tags: django, file-browser, django-tinymce

I am using django tinymce for a text field in django form. It is not admin based.

For inserting images, I tried django-tinymce-filebrowser. It is giving me following error in firefox error console in tiny_mce.js file:

```
TypeError: p is undefined
```

Also the browse button displays link to following javascript function:

```
openBrowser('srcbrowser','src','image','theme_advanced_image_image_browser_callback')
```

I am not getting from where it is coming.

My settings.py looks like this:

```
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG =  {
...
 'file_browser_callback': 'mce_filebrowser'
}
```

I tried searching for django-tinymce-filebrowser examples but nothing much is available. Most of the documentation is for django filebrowser which work in admin only.

Does anyone has clue how to configure this filebrowser?

Comment: did u solve this one?

Comment: No, the requirement changed. so this feature was not required in the editor